# Invalid write of size 4 array

Tags: c++, valgrind

i am making a Vector class in c++ and i am having some problems.

```
==23391== Invalid write of size 4
==23391==    at 0x401CAB: IntVector::IntVector(int, int) (IntVector.cpp:35)
==23391==    by 0x401009: main (main.cpp:36)
==23391==  Address 0x4c25218 is 0 bytes after a block of size 200 alloc'd
==23391==    at 0x4A07152: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:363)
==23391==    by 0x401C7F: IntVector::IntVector(int, int) (IntVector.cpp:32)
==23391==    by 0x401009: main (main.cpp:36)



IntVector::IntVector(int size, int value){
capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
while(size >= capacity)
{
    capacity = capacity*2;
}
if(size < 0)
{
    count = 0;
    array = new int[capacity];
}
else
{
    count = size;
    array = new int[capacity];  // line 32
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            array[i] = value; //line 36
        }
}
```

why could i be reading or writing past the array? in main i declare `v1(5,0)` and `initial capacity = 50` and the loop only goes to 4 so there is no way it should be reading or writing past 50!

Comment: Try printing `i` in the loop.

Comment: I can't reproduce it from the code and snippets of information you've posted: [this test case](http://ideone.com/vYpa8B) runs under Valgrind with no errors (and still does if I replace `50` with `capacity` per your edit). Perhaps you could post a complete test case, so we can see that the input really is what you think it is?

Comment: Where is your testcase?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this

> array = new int[50];  // line 32

be this?

```
array = new int[capacity];
```